# Spin effect flash gallery, require script logic

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gallery, spinner, image-gallery

Im developing a flash based image gallery with a spin effect. at once you see only few images but you should have the option to reveal more images similar to this design [1]: http://www.templatesrule.com/web-templates/template-preview/3364.jpg [Flash Photography Template]: http://www.templatesrule.com/web-templates/view-template-3364.html 
I need the logic, should i just play with the tweens or it could be dynamic with action script?

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a segmented wheel to turn around when you click, timeline tweens would be fine. You can get quite far with timeline tweens, and masks, but there are some features in that template (like the way the segments move to allow the one under the mouse more space) which would require a bit of scripting.